# Angularjs not two way binding for select with multiple

Tags: angularjs, html, binding

I have a select like:

```
<select multiple ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectMulti" ng-options="br.Name for br in branches"></select>
```

Scope objects in controller are as below:

```
vehicleFactory.getBranches().success(function (data) {
    $scope.branches = data;
}).error(function (data) {       
    $scope.loading = false;
});

vehicleFactory.getVehicle().success(function (data) {
    $scope.vehicle = data;
    $scope.selectMulti = $scope.vehicle.AssociatedBranches;
}).error(function (data) {       
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

It is not selecting multiple items in select as it was not binding.

What is wrong in it.

Comment: Please share more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<select multiple..>` the ViewModel of it is an array (unlike `<select>` without multiple).

So, say you have:

```
$scope.branches = [{...}, {...}, ...];
```

and the View:

```
<select multiple ng-model="selectMulti" ng-options="br.Name for br in branches">
</select>
```

Then, if you would like to select default values, your `$scope.selectMulti` should be an array of these values:

```
$scope.selectMulti = [$scope.branches[0], $scope.branches[1]];
```